# How to tell which x86asm is "faster"?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

I know different compilers generate different x86asm for different machines and same x86asm require a different amount of clock cycles to run on different machines. However, what are general guidelines?

For example, I currently have the following code where I want to use "abstraction at no overhead", but I am unable to verify whether foo (abstration over bar) is actually slower and how much than bar.

```
foo(ComputeArray<double, 4ul>&, double):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        movapd  xmm1, xmm0
        addsd   xmm0, xmm0
        unpcklpd        xmm1, xmm1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        unpcklpd        xmm0, xmm0
        movupd  xmm3, XMMWORD PTR [rax+224]
        movupd  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rax+240]
        movupd  xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rax+272]
        mulpd   xmm3, xmm1
        mulpd   xmm2, xmm1
        movupd  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax+256]
        mulpd   xmm1, xmm0
        mulpd   xmm0, xmm4
        addpd   xmm1, xmm3
        addpd   xmm0, xmm2
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+192], xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+208], xmm0
        ret
bar(double (*) [4], double):
        movapd  xmm2, xmm0
        movupd  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+256]
        movupd  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+272]
        movupd  xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+224]
        movupd  xmm6, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+240]
        unpcklpd        xmm2, xmm2
        addpd   xmm1, xmm1
        addpd   xmm0, xmm0
        addpd   xmm1, xmm4
        addpd   xmm0, xmm6
        mulpd   xmm1, xmm2
        mulpd   xmm0, xmm2
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+192], xmm1
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi+208], xmm0
        ret
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607391).  The 2nd version does fewer shuffles, fewer total uops, less indirection so shorter latency.  Depending on the CPU, you might still just bottleneck on addpd/mulpd throughput with out-of-order exec hiding the extra overhead, but if there's any independent work in the surrounding code, that could be running instead of that extra overhead.

Comment: These functions are mostly so small that you'd want them to inline for any real use-case; with no call-preserved XMM regs, the x86-64 SysV calling convention heavily favours inlining for small FP functions to avoid spill/reload.